# UPDATE does not use INDEX, but SELECT does

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I'm actually struggling understanding the problem here. I read everywhere saying that UPDATE benefits from indexes on the WHERE clause.

However, this query,

```
UPDATE `documents` SET `read`="1" WHERE `docid` IN (<subquery>)
```

**does not** seem to be using an index.
The table `documents` has an index on `docid` and on `read`.

When I do an `EXPLAIN`, I see `possible_keys = NULL` and `rows = 8011008` (full table). The subquery does use keys and read the proper rows (2 rows).

In the other hand, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE `docid` IN (<subquery>)
```

**does use** the index on `docid` and runs very quickly. It reads a few more rows than needed (as per `EXPLAIN`), but totally acceptable.

**Is there any explanation for this?**
I use MariaDB 10.

As a funny note (regarding `SELECT`), if in the `<subquery>` I use a `UNION`, while the subquery seems to get the proper number of rows, it seems the primary query does NOT use the index and does a full table scan.

If in the `UPDATE` I use `JOIN` instead of `IN`, the indexes are properly used. I resolved my problems by using `JOIN`.

Comment: The MySQL optimizer is known to treat sub-queries badly (in general and especially with DML statements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address the question "UPDATE does not use INDEX, but SELECT does"...

Until very recently, many `UPDATEs` were processed by different code than `SELECTs`.  Recently, there was a unification in the Oracle branch.  I don't think it has made its way into MariaDB yet.

Also, the construct `IN ( SELECT ... )` has been optimized very poorly until 5.6.  Again, MariaDB may or may not have yet included some of the 5.6/5.7 improvements in this area.

It is almost always better to turn `... IN ( SELECT ... )` into `JOIN ... ON ...`.  Such is possible in `UPDATE`; see "multi-table UPDATE".

For more discussion of your specific cases, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

I'm not saying that the Oracle branch necessarily does things better; rather that there could be a difference.

Comment: What you say makes sense! Thank you very much :)

Comment: amazing answer! now people at work think i'm smart! :)