# MySQL 5.7 UPDATE slow due to not using index

Tags: replication, index, update, mysql-5.7

We have an issue similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153293/update-does-not-use-index-but-select-does). Only, the solution there won't work for us as:

1. We don't use multi-table `JOINS`, but `` UPDATE … WHERE `userid` IN (<list of 10k ids>); ``
2. We currently "only" have the issue on one replication slave, so we can't change the statement there.

Forcing the update to use an index using `… USE INDEX (PRIMARY) SET …` would help, according to `EXPLAIN`.

Is there any way using variables to get similar behaviour? Or is our best approach to change the application to use explicit index hints & rebuild the slave?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the IN list with a table holding the 10k IDs?

Comment: > We currently "only" have the issue on one replication slave, so we can't change the statement there.

Would if we could…

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but – does that circumstance prevent you from even trying a rewritten version of the statement to see if the index would be used?

Comment: Only the fact that it's a read-only slave & I can't create new tables for a sub-select. Also, it won't solve the immediate problem of our replication being 2 days behind by now.

Answer (score 0):

So, for others, we found a solution.

TL;DR:

```
SET GLOBAL range_optimizer_max_mem_size=0;
```

and stop/start the slave.

---

According to the documentation on [limiting range optimization memory usage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#range-optimization-memory-use), the default maximum is 8 MiB. Also, there is this:

> For a simple query such as the following, where there is one candidate key for the range access method, each predicate combined with OR uses approximately 230 bytes:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t
> WHERE a=1 OR a=2 OR a=3 OR .. . a=N;
> ```
>
> […]
>
> For a query with IN() predicates:
>
> ```
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t
> WHERE a IN (1,2, ..., M) AND b IN (1,2, ..., N);
> ```
>
> Each literal value in an IN() list counts as a predicate combined with OR.

So that would mean our `UPDATE` with 10k simple IDs would need 10.000 * 230 Bytes = approx. 2,2 MiB, well within the default memory size. Even with the pre-5.7.11 requirement of 700 Bytes / predicate we'd be save.

Only, apparently the documentation is wrong, because as soon as we set the value of `range_optimizer_max_mem_size` to 0 (means No Limit), the replication delay went down from 3 hours to 0 in a span of less than 15 minutes.